# Attribute Directive is mark as error even on newly created Angular Project

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I've encounter problem with newly created Angular Project in Visual Studio Code where attribute directive like [ngClass], [ngSwitch] and etc is shown as error in .html file. Below is the standard app.component.html created as part of ng new .

[app.component.html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60z60.png)

In app.module.ts, I've import CommonModule as suggested in various online site as below: -

[app.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax22k.png)

After adding it, the error in .html file is still there. However this error does not give any issue when I run **ng serve** command and the page is able to be viewed in browser and working fine.

I have tried do some read up online but can't find any which is having similar issue.

Below is the Angular version for my workspace: -

[angular cli version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjiGY.png)

Since I'm new to Angular, nothing much has been done apart from trying out some suggestion found online like import CommonModule in app.module.ts. I have spend almost 3 days doing a lot of search and read up but can't find much having similar issue. I did uninstall and reinstall Angular Language Service but to no effect.

Help from fellow developer will be greatly appreciated. Thanks everyone in advance

[updated with code]
partial of app.component.html file

```
  <div class="terminal" [ngSwitch]="selection.value"> <!-- [ngSwitch] giving error -->
      <pre *ngSwitchDefault>ng generate component xyz</pre>
      <pre *ngSwitchCase="'material'">ng add @angular/material</pre>
      <pre *ngSwitchCase="'pwa'">ng add @angular/pwa</pre>
      <pre *ngSwitchCase="'dependency'">ng add _____</pre>
      <pre *ngSwitchCase="'test'">ng test</pre>
      <pre *ngSwitchCase="'build'">ng build</pre>
  </div>
```

app.module.ts file

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Angular CLI Version

```
Angular CLI: 16.1.4
Node: 18.16.1
Package Manager: npm 9.5.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 16.1.6
Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1601.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   16.1.4
@angular-devkit/core            16.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.1.4
@angular/cli                    16.1.4
@schematics/angular             16.1.4
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.1.6
```

Error message: -

```
(directive) NgSwitch
Can't bind to 'ngSwitch' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.ngtsc(-998002)
app.component.ts(2, 26): Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
```

[Update - Comparison between my old Angular test project]
Sorry, it's easier to show in image rather than code.
I suspect it's some version compatibility issue since when I remove CommonModule from my older version test project, the error shown is different from the error given in newer version. Please help to enlighten.

[Angular version 16.1.6 vs 14.1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxMBk.png)

But obviously I'm not expert in this hence I'm looking for help here. Thanks again

Comment: Just try restarting VS Code

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of screenshots

Comment: @RituparnaWarwatkar yup, I've did that multiple time and not helping. Thanks for responding.

Comment: @AluanHaddad noted, I've included the code. Basically it's default code generated by "ng new" command, I have not even started to code anything except for adding an import of CommonModule in app.module.ts file. Thanks for responding too

Comment: Try this commend  Ctrl + Shift + P on Windows and Linux or Command + Shift + P on macOS, then type Reload Window and select Developer: Reload Window.

Comment: @KhaledAyed thanks for the suggestion, that was also tried but to no effect too. Anyway I have manage to get the issue resolve. I would update once I really confirm it. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to pinpoint the problem. It is due to Angular Language Service.
Below are the step taken: -

1. Update Visual Studio Code version (for my case is 1.80.1)
2. Uninstall and then re-install Angular Language Service Extension

After the above step, attribute directive like [ngClass], [ngSwitch] and etc no longer show error in .html file.
Further verification is done by removing CommonModule from app.module.ts file and check the error message, now the error shown is the same as error shown in my test project with Angular version 14.1.1

Hope this help whoever who have similar issue.
Thanks and have a great day

Thanks to @Rituparna Warwatkar for highlighting on VS Code which make me try to work on something on this direction.